# ZF2, dependencies which I don't know at start

Tags: zend-framework2

In my controller, via service, I get from DB a list of the names of widgets (eg. chart, calendar, etc). Every widget implements WidgetInterface and may need other services as its own dependencies. The list of widgets can be different for each user, so I don't know which widgets / dependencies I will need in my controller. Generally, I put dependencies via DI, using factories, but in this case I don't know dependencies at the time of controller initialization.
I want to avoid using service locator directly in controller. How can I manage that issue? Should I get a list of the names of widgets in controller factory? And depending on widgets list get all dependencies and put them to controller?

Thanks, Tom

**Solution**

I solved my issue in a way that suggested Kwido and Sven Buis, it means, I built my own Plugin Manager.

Advantages: I do not need use service locator directly in controller and I have clear and extensible way to get  different kinds of widgets.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own Manager, like some sort of ServiceManager, for your widgets.

```
class WidgetManager extends AbstractPluginManager
```

Take a look at: [Samsonik tutorial - pluginManager](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/zend-framework-2-getting-closer-with-pluginmanager/). So this way you can inject the WidgetManager and only retrieve the widgets from this manager as your function: `validatePlugin`, checks whether or not the fetched instance is using the `WidgetInterface`. Keep in mind that you can still call the parent ServiceManager.

Or keep it simple and build a plugin for your controller that maps your widget names to the service. This plugin can then use the serviceLocator/Manager to retrieve your widget(s), whether they're created by factories or invokableFactories. So you dont inject all the widget directly but only fetch them when they're requested. Something realy simplistic:

```php
protected $map = [
    // Widget name within the plugin => Name or class to call from the serviceManager
    'Charts' => Widget\Charts::class,
];

public function load($name)
{
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->map)) {
        return $this->getServiceManager()->get($this->map[$name]);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Injecting all the Widgets might be bad for your performance so you might consider something else, as when the list of your widgets grow so will the time to handle your request.

Hope this helped you and pushed you in some direction.

Answer (score 1):

This indeed is a interesting question. You could consider using Plugins for the widgets, which can be loaded on the fly.

Depency injection is a good practise, but sometimes, with dynamic content, impossible to implement.

Another way to do this, is to make your own widget-manager. This manager then can load the specific widgets you need. The widget-manager can be injected into the controller.

Edit:
As you can see above, same idea from @kwido.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a separate service and inject that into the controller.

```
interface UserWidgetServiceInterface
{
    public function __construct(array $widgets);
    public function getWidget($name);
}
```

The controller factory

```
class MyControllerFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ControllerManager $controllerManager, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $serviceLocator = $controllerManager->getServiceLocator();

        $userWidgetService = $serviceLocator->get('UserWidgetService');

        return new MyController($userWidgetService);
    }
}
```

Then the logic to load the widgets would be moved to the `UserWidgetServiceFactory`.

```
public function UserWidgetServiceFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ServiceManager $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $userId = 123; // Load from somewhere e.g session, auth service.

        $widgetNames = $this->getWidgetNames($serviceLocator, $userId); 
        $widgets = $this->loadWidgets($serviceManager, $widgetNames);

        return new UserWidgetService($widgets);
    }

    public function getWidgetNames(ServiceManager $sm, $userId)
    {
       return ['foo','bar'];
    }

    public function loadWidgets(serviceManager $sm, array $widgets)
    {
        $w = [];
        foreach($widgets as $widgetName) {
            $w[$widgetName] = $sm->get($widgetName);
        }
        return $w;
    }   
}
```

The call to `loadWidgets()` would eager load all the widgets; should you wish to optimise this you could register your widgets as [`LazyServices`](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.service-manager.lazy-services.html)